# We Clicked on any Option it jumps to that one but does not get back

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

###### Here I have created a Menu where if I click on any letter the scroller jumps to that letter option to the menu click on Black backgrounded header Alphabet and select the desired letter. I have used js for this and I only works in ascending order top to bottom but not bottom to top

- What I want is when I click a from the bottom it must take me to the A letter
- It's Going from A to Any letter below but not bottom to top

_Click on the dark background header to get into the Menu

```js
function wordbar(){
let y = document.getElementById("Invisible");
  
if(y.className === "Hiddenbox"){
  document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("Invisible").style.visibility = "visible"; 
}else{
    document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "auto";
    document.getElementById("Invisible").style.display = "none";
}
}


function Removebar(letter){
   const hiddenbox = document.getElementById("Invisible").className;
  if(hiddenbox === "Hiddenbox"){
    document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "auto";
    document.getElementById("Invisible").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById(`${letter}-letter`).scrollIntoView();

  }else{
    document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "";
    document.getElementById("Invisible").style.display = "";
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: auto;
}
.Mainbox{
  width: 100%;
}

h2{
  height: 30px;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li{
  font-family: poppins;
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

ul{
  padding: 0px;
}



.Hiddenbox{
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/*   background-color: #d2d2d2;
  */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
.container{
  width: 45%;
  padding: 30px 50px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 10px;
  max-height: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid dimgrey;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  position: relative;
}

.click-lines{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid dimgrey;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease; 
  color: white;
  text-align: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.click-lines:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

.togglebar{
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dela+Gothic+One&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Nanum+Gothic:wght@400;700;800&family=Neonderthaw&family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto+Condensed&family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Zen+Kaku+Gothic+Antique:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="Mainbox" id="box">
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="a-letter">A</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Appiv</li>
    <li>Ananus</li>
    <li>Ambar</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="b-letter">B</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Bejing</li>
    <li>brothal</li>
    <li>brother</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="c-letter">C</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Cat</li>
    <li>cow</li>
    <li>calculas</li>
    <li>car</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="d-letter">D</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Dat</li>
    <li>Dow</li>
    <li>Dalculas</li>
    <li>Dar</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="e-letter">E</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Eat</li>
    <li>Eow</li>
    <li>Ealculas</li>
    <li>Ear</li>
  </ul>
<h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="f-letter">F</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Feet</li>
    <li>Form</li>
    <li>fungus</li>
    <li>Fan</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="g-letter">G</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Grasp</li>
    <li>Grow</li>
    <li>Game</li>
    <li>Goat</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="h-letter">H</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>hola</li>
    <li>Hampter</li>
    <li>Hercules</li>
    <li>Hear</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="i-letter">I</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Ice</li>
    <li>Igloo</li>
    <li>Intence</li>
    <li>Irrigation</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="j-letter">J</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Jasmine</li>
    <li>Justin</li>
    <li>Jungle</li>
    <li>Jam</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="k-letter">K</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>kit-kat</li>
    <li>Kurlus</li>
    <li>Kampu</li>
    <li>kalli</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 href="javascript:void()" onclick="wordbar()" id="l-letter">L</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Lambord</li>
    <li>Last</li>
    <li>Lamb</li>
    <li>Lamp</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="Hiddenbox" id="Invisible">
    <div class="container">
      <li href="#A" onclick="Removebar('a')" class="click-lines">A</li>
      <li href="#B" onclick="Removebar('b')" class="click-lines">B</li>
      <li href="#C" onclick="Removebar('c')" class="click-lines">C</li>
      <li href="#D" onclick="Removebar('d')" class="click-lines">D</li>
      <li href="#E" onclick="Removebar('e')" class="click-lines">E</li>
      <li href="#F" onclick="Removebar('f')" class="click-lines">F</li>
      <li href="#G" onclick="Removebar('g')" class="click-lines">G</li>
      <li href="#H" onclick="Removebar('h')" class="click-lines">H</li>
      <li href="#I" onclick="Removebar('i')" class="click-lines">I</li>
      <li href="#J" onclick="Removebar('j')"class="click-lines">J</li>
      <li href="#K" onclick="Removebar('k')"class="click-lines">K</li>
      <li href="#L" onclick="Removebar('l')"class="click-lines">L</li>
      <li href="#M" onclick="Removebar('m')"class="click-lines">M</li>
      <li href="#N" onclick="Removebar('n')"class="click-lines">N</li>
      <li href="#O" onclick="Removebar('o')"class="click-lines">O</li>
      <li href="#P" onclick="Removebar('p')"class="click-lines">P</li>
      <li href="#Q" onclick="Removebar('q')"class="click-lines">Q</li>
      <li href="#R" onclick="Removebar('r')"class="click-lines">R</li>
      <li href="#S" onclick="Removebar('s')"class="click-lines">S</li>
      <li href="#T" onclick="Removebar('t')"class="click-lines">T</li>
      <li href="#U" onclick="Removebar('u')"class="click-lines">U</li>
      <li href="#V" onclick="Removebar('v')"class="click-lines">V</li>
      <li href="#W" onclick="Removebar('w')"class="click-lines">W</li>
      <li href="#X" onclick="Removebar('x')"class="click-lines">X</li>
      <li href="#Y" onclick="Removebar('y')"class="click-lines">Y</li>
      <li href="#Z" onclick="Removebar('z')"class="click-lines">Z</li>
      <li class="togglebar" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Removebar()" >&times;</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

_

> Please use it on full page ⚠️

To use Click on

Here is the code

Answer (score 0):

scrollIntoView() is only scrolling down, to solve that add `document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;` before `document.getElementById(letter+'-letter').scrollIntoView();`.